# Stretch ImageView height and maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way in android to display an ImageView by maintaining it's aspect ratio but increasing the height before doing so.

So for example, I have different images that I store inside an ImageView by maintaining it's aspect ratio:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coupon_detail_barcode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

So, let's say the image that comes in is 40dp height and 40dp width. Instead of maintaining that original ratio, I want to stretch the image out first to 42dp height, 40dp width, THEN having it displayed maintaining those new ratios.

I'm assuming there is no way to do it in XML and would have to do it all programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the image as a byte array then:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);

// Adjust size here.
Bitmap adjustedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false));

// Set adjustedBitmap into ImageView
someImageView.setImageBitmap(adjustedBitmap);
```